# Reflection IllegalArgumentException java

Tags: java, reflection

What i am trying to do: get the value of the a reflected field named "f3" with the type "K". I would like to be able to use the value of f3 to reflect fields from within it. (edit)f3 is inside class b which is from a .jar file. (edit)

All methods of getting the value that i try give the error: can not set K field f3 to java.lang.Class.

Question: How can i get the value of the field `f3` (which has the type `K`) on the class `b` (which is a class loaded from an external jar) ?

The following code throws an `IllegalArgumentException` :

```
Class instance = loadClass("b"); // simplified for readability
Field fieldf3 = instance.getDeclaredField("f3");
fieldf3.setAccessible(true);
Object value = fieldf3.get(instance); //exception on this line.
```

StackTrace :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set K field b.f3 to java.lang.Class
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve the value of the field on a `Class<B>` instance instead of doing it on an instance of the class representend by what you (quite clumsily) called `instance` in your code. To be clear, you are doing like if `f3` was a static field of the class `B` (a field of `Class<B>` is indeed a static field of `B`) whereas it is actually a non-static field. Thus, you need to get an instance of `B` before calling the `get` method :

```
Class<?> clazz  = loadClass("b");
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
Fied fieldf3    = B.class.getDeclaredField("f3");
fieldf3.setAccessible(true);
fieldf3.get(instance);
```

Let's see with an example (this time let's assume that B is a class defined in the main file) :

```
static class B {
    private int f3;
    public B(int f) {
        f3 = f;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new b(17);
    Field field = B.class.getDeclaredField("f3");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(field.get(b));
}
```

This code will output `17` as expected. Now, imagine that `f3` is a static field, then it becomes a field on any `Class<B>` instance (actually, I think it is a singleton so there is only a single such instance), then you could add `System.out.println(field.get(B.class));` and it would still work. The value of the field will also be accessible from any instance of `B` so `System.out.println(field.get(b));` will also work.

Comment: instance is b.class, b has the field f3 of type K inside it. b is from a .jar file

Comment: instance is not K class

Comment: Yes, in my code currently, your K k is my b instance, and your int f3 is the K f3 value i want but field.get(instance) is what gives problem

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add how i got b, my b instance is loaded via URLClassLoader.loadClass("b") and calling the main method of b

Comment: <code>Method main = instance.getMethod("main", new Class[] {args.getClass()});
        
        main.setAccessible(true);
        try {
        main.invoke(instance, new Object[] {args});
        } catch(IllegalAccessException exc) {
            
        }</code>

Comment: Class instance = loadClass("b");

Comment: @TKG As I thought. It is incorrect, don't you see why, basing on my answer ? I don't know if `b` has a default constructor, but if it does, rename `instance clazz` and then do `b instance = clazz.newInstance()`.

Comment: how can i do b instance = ..... if b is a class loaded from a .jar? is their an alternative or am i missing somthing

Comment: Yes sorry, it is wrong, but `Object instance = clazz.newInstance()` should do

Comment: Thank you!! can you please put what i did wrong into words for my personal learning? btw it works perfectly now.

Comment: Sorry, I was out.  I already explained that in my answer but I will try to find another way to say it.